# php get data encoding on ie

Tags: php, encoding, get

I m sending some form data (with get) to a popup with a javascript function.
Both pages have utf-8 encoding. But popup showing special values wrong (like �). This problem happens on Internet Explorer only. It returns normal when i change ie encoding to windows-1254. Page encoding should stay same.
Checked $_GET data with mb_detect_encoding(); it gives UTF-8 result.
Any idea what can cause this?

```
function NewCustomer(field1,field2,field3){
OpenPopup('Customer/New.php?field1='+ field1 +'&field2='+ field2 +'&field3='+ field3 +'', 'NewCustomer', 'channelmode=0, directories=0, fullscreen=0, width=550, height=460, location=0, menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, status=0, titlebar=1, toolbar=0', false);
}


echo $_GET['fieldname'];


 function OpenPopup( url, winname, features )
   {
    if(winname==''){
     window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     return;
    }
    if ( !findWindow( url, winname, features ) )
    {
     var handle = window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     if ( handle != null ) handle.focus();
    }
   }

   function findWindow( url, winname, features )
   {
    var handle = window.open( '', winname, features, false );
    if ( handle != null )
    {
     if (( handle.location != 'about:blank' ) && ( handle.location != '' ))
     {
      handle.focus();
      return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
   }
```

**EDIT**

I fixed IE problem with iconv. But now, the problem started on other browsers.

```
iconv('windows-1254', 'UTF-8', $_GET['field']);
```

**LAST EDIT**

Here is final solution.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['fieldname'])) {
preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
if (count($matches)>1){ echo iconv('windows-1254', 'UTF-8', $_GET['fieldname']); } else { echo $_GET['fieldname']; }
 } ?>
```

Comment: Without the code, we'd all be guessing.

Comment: Is `OpenPopup` a standard PHP function? I cannot find its documentation.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Its not. I added function code.

Comment: Most likely not related, but the [featurelist string isn't allowed to contain spaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open).

Answer (score 0):

Check the file encoding. Some text editors like Notepad++ store the file code content in that encoding.

I think the javascript file is not in UTF-8 encoding.

And if it's working in ALL browsers but IE, you will not go to hell. Blame Microsoft for that and FORGET Internet Explorer.

Comment: Checked, both pages are encoded with UTF-8 without BOM.
Javascript in the same page. Tried to add charset="utf-8" to js, too.

Answer (score 0):

In you $_GET var, use this:

```
echo utf8_encode($_GET['my_var']);
```

or

```
echo utf8_decode($_GET['my_var']);
```

Update: I tested with, and looks fine

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $field);
```

I hope it helps ;)

Saludos.

Comment: utf8_decode makes � > ?
utf8_encode makes � > ð or þ (according to character)
Both doesnt fix.

Comment: Yes, no problem in address bar.
New.php?field=şğç