# php post to pop up with second button

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a search form with five fields and two buttons. I want to post field values to pop up with second button.

I am using get method but it has encoding problems;
[php get data encoding on ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896349/php-get-data-encoding-on-ie)

```
window.name = 'SearchCustomer';
   function OpenPopup( url, winname, features )
   {
    if(winname==''){
     window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     return;
    }
    if ( !findWindow( url, winname, features ) )
    {
     var handle = window.open( url, winname, features, false );
     if ( handle != null ) handle.focus();
    }
   }

   function findWindow( url, winname, features )
   {
    var handle = window.open( '', winname, features, false );
    if ( handle != null )
    {
     if (( handle.location != 'about:blank' ) && ( handle.location != '' ))
     {
      handle.focus();
      return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
   }


function OpenCustomer(customerid){
    OpenPopup('Customer/new.php?id='+ customerid +'', 'CustomerForm', 'channelmode=0, directories=0, fullscreen=0, width=550, height=460, location=0, menubar=0, resizable=0, scrollbars=1, status=0, titlebar=1, toolbar=0', false);
}
```

I can't add onSubmit event because search button should work on same page.

How can i post form to pop up with second button?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: @BenM I added a get sample i used. I didn't tried something for post method.

Comment: @RavinderSingh Code is a search form with five fields and two submit button.

Comment: Instead of Opening Pop up, have a lightbox like this : http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Comment: @RavinderSingh I can't, opened pop up should keep working on that pop up.

Answer (score 1):

@milesh You can do this by either proper URL encode, So that IE is not break or Store the form field values in javascript varible which is associate with "window" object. Later once your popup window is loaded then access those variable from child window.

For example,
In Parent window,

```
window.myform = { field1:"searchtext", field2:"somecategory"}
```

Now you can get those variables in child window as follows,

```
alert(opener.myform);
```

Note: Not an exact code. This is some generic idea to achieve your goal.

Comment: **URL encode** gave me idea and i fixed [get problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896349/php-get-data-encoding-on-ie) with `encodeURI(field1)`. Thanks.